# c++ Debug Assertion Failed on HTTP Request

Tags: c++, http, casablanca

I'm doing some code where i need to do a GET request and manipulate the info received. For this i'm using C++ REST SDK (codename "Casablanca") for the request

This is my code

```
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>

using namespace utility;                    
using namespace web;                        
using namespace web::http;                 
using namespace web::http::client;          
using namespace concurrency::streams;    


//This method i saw on the Microsoft documentation
pplx::task<void> HTTPStreamingAsync()
{    
    http_client client(L"http://localhost:10000/Something"); //The api is running at the moment

    // Make the request and asynchronously process the response. 

    return client.request(methods::GET).then([](http_response response)
    {
        // Print the status code.
        std::wostringstream ss;
        ss << L"Server returned returned status code " << response.status_code() << L'.' << std::endl;
        std::wcout << ss.str();

        // TODO: Perform actions here reading from the response stream.
        auto bodyStream = response.body();

        // In this example, we print the length of the response to the console.
        ss.str(std::wstring());
        ss << L"Content length is " << response.headers().content_length() << L" bytes." << std::endl;
        std::wcout << ss.str();
    });
}   



void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   HTTPStreamingAsync().wait();
   //...
}
```

And when i use debug i get error on the following line:

return client.request(methods::GET).then([](http_response response)

With debug i see that variable "client" has content, but i still receive this error:

[Image with the Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H9cI.png)

I google it the error, and most of the people say that it is error on the code (trying to access some parts of the memory)...

Any ideas?

Comment: Somewhere else, you may have `__acrt_first_block == header` and this is being used as an assertion, which fails (`false`). The Microsoft code you pasted in your question is performing that assertion and indicates it... So you may need to add more details in order for people to help you.

Comment: I searched in all files from the project and i didn't find any " __acrt_first_block == header ".The code above its all the code i have in this project

Comment: Now i fixed the problem. Now i have other problem with the response body that always return 1, but i will fix it!. Thanks all for the help! :)

Comment: Well done @Tazz, can you please post an answer to your own question explaining how you solved your problem? This may help other people, and you may get reputation by doing so.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can happen when the cpprestsdk DLL is build with `Multi-Threaded DLL` `/MD` and the calling library is build with `Multi-Threaded` `/MT`. Since the cpprestsdk does not offer a configuration for a .lib file, you are forced to use `/MD`. At least that is best to my knowledge, as I haven't been able to compile cpprestsdk.lib out of the box without a bunch of linker errors.